# symfony2 custom form type - own defaultOptions

Tags: symfony

i'm creating an own form type in symfony2 but i cannot access my own defaultOptions in the buildView function. Here is the code:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{        
    return array(
        'identifier' => isset($options['identifier']) ? $options['identifier'] : '#star',
        'currentRating' => isset($options['currentRating']) ? $options['currentRating'] : 0,
    );
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
{                
    $view->set('currentRating', $form->getAttribute('currentRating'));
    $view->set('idientifier', $form->getAttribute('identifier'));
}
```

The error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: currentRating in ...
```

I don't read anything that this is not possible.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method `buildForm` of your type, you need to set explicitly the attribute you want to use in  the method `buildView`. Here is how you should do it:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    // Code here

    $builder->setAttribute('currentRating', $options['currentRating']);
    $builder->setAttribute('identifier', $options['identifier']);
} 

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
{
    $view->set('currentRating', $form->getAttribute('currentRating'));
    $view->set('identifier', $form->getAttribute('identifier'));
}
```

This should do the trick.
Hope this helps.

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

@Matt's answer is great but just a notice for anyone using Symfony 2.1+:

A third argument was added (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md) to buildView called array $options which is required so make sure you add this.

So if you're using Symfony 2.1+ do this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    // Code here

    $builder->setAttribute('currentRating', $options['currentRating']);
    $builder->setAttribute('identifier', $options['identifier']);
} 

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->set('currentRating', $form->getAttribute('currentRating'));
    $view->set('identifier', $form->getAttribute('identifier'));
}
```